# Django: putting secret key into crontab file

Tags: python, django, cron, django-settings

According to the Greenfeld-Roy book "Two scoops of Django", putting the secret key into an environment variable instead of the settings file is a good practice. So I followed this advice, but that lead to problems when trying to execute a self-written management command in a cronjob.

After a bit I figured out that I had to include the secret key environment variable into the crontab file itself, otherwise manage.py was unable to load external modules (this is due to the fact that cron doesn't know of anything but a small subset of environment variables). So after the fix, my crontab file looks like this:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=my-project-secret-key

0 0 * * * path/to/python path/to/manage.py management_command
```

I'd like to know if it's a good solution or if is there any other (maybe more pythonic?) way of addressing this issue.

Comment: Using celery/celerybeat to schedule tasks is an alternative

Comment: Yeah, I know about celery, but the task is really a light one, seems to me that using a distributed task queue is a bit of an overwork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to put the command in a shell script and then call the program via cron. This way the cron file would look simpler and you could keep the exports in a separate file and then source them in all the other scripts.

Example script (run_command.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=my-project-secret-key
path/to/python path/to/manage.py management_command
```

This script can now be called in the cron file

`0 0 * * * path/to/run_command.sh`

and make sure the shell file is executable

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to move the environment variables in another file, eg. `~/.env` and have your crontab look something like this:

```
0 5 * * * source $HOME/.env; /path/to/command/to/run
```

Comment: This is useful too, I just find the other solution a little bit cleaner. Thank you nonetheless.